# Same conflicts appears again and again with the rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have a **develop** branch from which I branched out the **feature** branch, worked in the feature branch then I pushed the changes.

Later **develop** branch had some commits ahead of my **feature** branch thus I rebased the develop branch on my feature branch using `git rebase origin/develop`. I had some conflicts during this rebase which I resolved.

Everything is now working in my local feature branch. I can see the latest changes from developed rebased to my feature.

**Problem:**

Now if I again try to rebase my develop branch to my feature though nothing has changed recently. I am getting the same conflicts that I resolved earlier.  Is this expected?

What is the workaround such that the same conflicts don't arise for the same rebase without changing anything in develop and feature branch.

Comment: The exact details depend on the original conflicts, how you resolved them, and what has happened since then, but yes, this is normal.

Comment: Perhaps have a look to 'git rerere'